# Using WireMock how can we verify that a request of a given url has NOT been made?

Tags: java, wiremock

Given the following unit test, I can easily test if a request of a particular url has been made.  Is there a way to do the opposite, verify that a request of a particular url has NOT been made?

i.e. verify that a request was made:

```
stubFor(post(urlEqualTo("/login")));

webclient.submit(testLogin);

verify(postRequestedFor(urlMatching("/login")
```

What I'd like to do - Verify that a request was NOT made:

```
stubFor(post(urlEqualTo("/login")));

webclient.submit(testLogin);

verify(postRequestedFor(urlNotMatching("/login")
```

Answer (score 40):

`verify(exactly(0), postRequestedFor(urlEqualTo("/login")));`

Basically checking if exactly 0 calls were made.
To read more about it. see [here](http://wiremock.org/docs/verifying/)

Comment: If you want to verify that no requests at all have been made: `verify(0, anyRequestFor(anyUrl()));`

Comment: The above answer is correct, there is just a small typo, the method is `anyRequestedFor` instead of `anyRequestFor`.

Answer (score 0):

There response above works. For more complex asserts, WireMock Admin REST API allows retrieving all requests in the journal - [GET:
/__admin/requests](https://wiremock.org/docs/standalone/admin-api-reference/). In your unit tests, e.g. with a Native Java library JUnit rules or with a Testcontainers module, you can:

1. Provision a fresh instance via a test rule, or do s [DELETE:
   /__admin/requests](https://wiremock.org/docs/standalone/admin-api-reference/) request over the REST API
2. Run whatever test logic you have
3. Call [GET: /__admin/requests](https://wiremock.org/docs/standalone/admin-api-reference/) REST API to retrieve the list of requests
4. Process this list to see that what actually was received by WireMock and how it was matched